# mysql - Select where image_url=0 but return all rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to accomplish the following sql statement

the expected result are only image_url having 0 value

> SELECT product_id,image_url FROM `tour_product` where image_url = 0

but i am getting all rows shows in below image

[image]

can any one help me why this happen.

Comment: Can you add your tables structure and what you mean by `having 0 value` ?

Comment: maybe you want LEN(image_url) = 0??

Comment: Or by _'0' (zero) value_, do you mean it is `NULL`?

Comment: Chintan Stop rolling back valuable edits. The post has been temporarily locked to stop the roll backs.

Answer (score 2):

Your `image_url` field data type is string so its not accept number so your use **single quote ' '.**

like

```
SELECT product_id, image_url FROM tour_product WHERE image_url = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string to an integer.  So, what is MySQL to do?

It does something you might not expect.  It converts the **string** to an **integer**.  It does so by converting leading characters.  If there are no leading digits, the value is zero.

Moral?  Don't mix types.  The logic would be:

```
where image_url = '0'
```

Or more likely, you want something like:

```
where image_url <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

for this You are looking for CHAR_LENGTH() to get the number of characters in a string.

```
SELECT product_id,image_url FROM tour_product where CHAR_LENGTH (image_url) = 0
```

OR

for this get all zero value

```
SELECT product_id,image_url FROM tour_product where CHAR_LENGTH (image_url) = '0';
```